# Is there a way to change the dataform default service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dataform

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/required-access#:%7E:text=When%20you%20create%20your%20first%20Dataform%20repository%2C%20Dataform%20automatically%20generates%20a%20service%20account.%20Dataform%20uses%20the%20service%20account%20to%20interact%20with%20BigQuery%20on%20your%20behalf.), a default service account is used to manage and execute dataform in GCP.

Is there a way to use another service account instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can now change service accounts in GCP Dataform.**

You have two options, the project service account and workflow config service accounts.

The project service account can be either set in the Create Repository dialogue:

[image: create repository dialogue with service account option]

Or via the Settings tab in the project itself:

[image: edit service account button]

[image: edit service account dialogue]

Workflow config service accounts can be edited in the create / edit dialogue for individual workflow configs:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the [google document](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/required-access#about_the_service_account_and_required_roles) ,it is not possible to use a custom service account with DataForm.DataForm  creates its own service account  and permissions by default.

However, there is a feature request [field](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/254626248) for the same. You can vote for this feature by clicking the "+1" and "STAR" mark to receive updates on it or you can also create a feature request thread in Google’s [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here is the link to the issue tracker feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/254626248

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a custom service account. I have tried this in cloud shell.

Step 1: Please follow the instructions to create and download a private key from the Google Cloud Console in JSON format.

Step 2:
Follow the steps in https://docs.dataform.co/dataform-cli to run dataform from your cloud shell.

a. At the step where you *Create a credentials file* using command *dataform init-creds bigquery* it will first ask for the location of your datasets and the location's region name.

[specify location of datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZJ3w.png)

[specify location's region name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEXhL.png)

b. It now asks if you want to use the Application Default Credentials or JSON Key.
Choose option 2
[Option to use default credentials or JSON key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHOrz.png)

Choose option 2.
It prompts you to enter the path to your Google Cloud private key file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11g0t.png) Provide the path to your key file json. <path/keyfile.json>
A new credentials file *.df-credentials.json* will be written to folder containing your provided details.

Step 3: Now run dataform using command *dataform run*

Hope this is what you were looking for.